# Difference of modified Bessel functions in integral form

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions

I know the following integral representation of modified Bessel functions of first kind:
$$I_q(\rho) = \frac{\left(\frac{\rho}{2}\right)^q}{\Gamma(q+1/2)\Gamma(1/2)} \int_{-1}^{1}e^{-\rho t}(1-t^2)^{q-1/2} dt $$
I wish to prove that
$$I_{-q}(\rho)-I_q(\rho) = \frac{\Gamma(1/2-q)\sin(2q\pi)\left(\frac{\rho}{2}\right)^q}{\pi\Gamma(1/2)}\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-\rho t}(t^2-1)^{q-1/2} dt$$

But I don't know which change of variable I must do to obtain this result, I don't understand how this integration limit change from $(-1\,\, \text{to}\,\, 1)$ to $(1\,\, \text{to}\,\, \infty$).

My final goal with this expressions is prove that
$$K_q(\rho) = \frac{\Gamma(1/2)\left(\rho/2\right)^q}{\Gamma(q+1/2)}\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-\rho t}(t^2-1)^{q-1/2} dt$$
where $K_q$ is the modified Bessel function of second kind which is defined for $q \not \in \mathbb{Z}$ as
$$ \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{I_{-q}(\rho)-I_q(\rho)}{\sin(q \pi)}.$$

If anyone knows another way to prove the integral representation for $K_q$ above, it will very helpful, thank you so much for the attention.

The integral representation above can be found in the book A treatise on the theory of Bessel functions writed by Watson, page $172$

**Update**: The problem is solved if the following formula is proved for $\rho >0$ and $q \geq0$

$$I_{-q}(\rho) = \frac{(\rho/2)^q}{\sqrt{2\pi}\Gamma(q+1/2)}\left[ \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} e^{\rho t}(1-t^2)^{q-1/2}dt+\sin(q \pi) \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-\rho t}(t^2-1)^{q-1/2} dt\right]$$

Comment: The integral formula given for $I_q(\rho)$ only works for $q > 1/2$. I'm finding it hard to find integral representations that work for arbitrary $q$.

Comment: same situation here, I want to calculate this difference because need to prove integral representation for Bessel functions of second kind $K_q$, Watson book pag 172 has something about it, but I don't understand very well, the text in this part is very concise.

Comment: Here I think $I_{-q}(x)$ is being defined as $i^{-q}J_{-q}(i x) = i^{-q}[\cos(\pi q)J_{q}(ix) -\sin(\pi q)Y_q(i x)]$. But most integral forms for $Y_\nu$ don't work for imaginary arguments so we run into a similar problem.

Comment: I will edit the question showing what I want to achieve with this expressions, this maybe helps us finding another alternatives of proof

Comment: Alternative solution: show that that integral satisfies the modified bessel equation of order $q$ and goes to 0 as $\rho\rightarrow \infty$. That uniquely defines $K_q$

Comment: This is a nice idea, where can I find a proof that this property uniquely defines $K_q$ ?